# Like/Dislike chatter feed not working in Community

Tags: community, chatter, chatter-feed

We need to give community user ability to like the feed item.
Tried below code.

```
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.updateLikeForFeedElement(communityId,feedItemId, true);
```

**Error:**

> System.NoAccessException: Insufficient Privileges: You do not have the
>   level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested.
>   Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access
>   is necessary.

This code is working with the standard user but not for the community user. Is there any setting for this?

Comment: can that user like posts from standard SF chatter ui?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yes, I am able to like from there

Comment: If I am not wrong ConnectAPI kinda uses rest callouts, can you try doing it by just inserting FeedLike ? `INSERT new FeedLike (FeedItemId = FeedEntityId);` . [FeedLike](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feedlike.htm)

Comment: @PranayJaiswal this is giving me the error = `You can like or unlike posts, comments, and other feed item types only after they're published.`

Comment: I can't think of anything else, on the last try can you try this bit.
`INSERT new FeedLike (FeedEntityId= FeedEntityId);`

Comment: @PranayJaiswal thanks! Eventually, It worked for me, but now not sure why did I run into the above error.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You can add that in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConnectApi does a callout using sessionId, as of now lightning session is not API enabled and that might be failing your code to like the post.

You can manually insert [FeedLike](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feedlike.htm)

```
INSERT new FeedLike (FeedItemId = FeedEntityId);
```